# how to get the each id from json and pass to update function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using nestable js(https://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/vNpvVw) to drag and drop .after drag the item is done i get the id of each items in console Like  [{"id":7},{"id":24},{"id":117}]

for this console value am using variable like

```
            var serializedData = window.JSON.stringify($($this).nestable('serialize'));
            console.log("sData:", serializedData)
```

And now i want to get the each id .and pass each id to my update function ....how can i achieve this using javascript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [{"id":7},{"id":24},{"id":117}];
   data.forEach(myFunction);
   function myFunction(item, index) {
    console.log(item.id);//you will get id 
    newFunction(item.id);
  }
```

Comment: is this code is working fine when we give the static data ...but am getting the values dynamiclly ....so it not working

Comment: I have achieve this by using var data =json.parse(serializedData);    Thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I Got the each id from JSON and pass the ID to One function.

```
             var serializedData = window.JSON.stringify($($this).nestable('serialize'));
             console.log("sData:", serializedData)
             // convert the JSON into Object
             var obj = JSON.parse(serializedData);
             obj.forEach(myFunction);
             function myFunction(item, index) {
                var eachid = item.id;
                console.log("Item-id", eachid);//you will get id 
                Newfunction(eachid);
            }
```